# How to derive efficient way in one list

Tags: python, list

suppose there are N1 ~ N9,
and efficiency of them :

```
efficiency = [0.12, 0.23, 0.34, 0.45, 0.56, 0.67, 0.78, 0.89, 1]
```

cost of them :

```
cost = [23371, 48543, 98714, 194859, 220429, 316429, 348286, 390143, 414714]
```

there is assumption

```
efficiency[A] > efficiency[b]  <=>  cost[A] > cost[B]
```

How can i derive the cheapest method to get total efficiency >=1 with lesser then 5 elements (repeating allowed) ?

Comment: Looks like https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this algorithm:

```
import itertools
efficiency = [0.12, 0.23, 0.34, 0.45, 0.56, 0.67, 0.78, 0.89, 1]
cost = [23371, 48543, 98714, 194859, 220429, 316429, 348286, 390143, 414714]
for item_num in range(1,5):
    options = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(len(efficiency)), item_num))
    valid_options = [o for o in options if sum([efficiency[o[i]] for i in range(len(o))]) >= 1]
    valid_costs = {vo: sum([cost[vo[i]] for i in range(len(vo))]) for vo in valid_options}
    item_num_best_option = min(valid_costs, key=valid_costs.get)
    item_num_best_cost = valid_costs[item_num_best_option]
    if item_num > 1:
        if item_num_best_cost < best_cost:
            best_option, best_cost = item_num_best_option, item_num_best_cost
    else:
        best_option, best_cost = item_num_best_option, item_num_best_cost
best_option
```

Output:

```
(1, 1, 1, 2) # Meaning use item 1 once, and item 2 three times
```

Concept:

You create all the possible options with `itertools` allowing repeatations. Then You filter out the options that don't reach `efficiency` 1. Then create a dictionary that calculates and holds the cost of each option. Then find the option with the least cost. And the whole process is inside a loop that checks all the combination numbers between 1 and 4 (inclusive).

Comment: This "algorithm" is called brute force.

Comment: Less than 5 items (if I understood the question correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Doing some research, it seems an integer linear programming problem (binary in this case). Because the objective function and the constraints are linear. [Integer programming problem are know for being NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). And NP-complete problems can be solved by a [restricted class of brute force search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness).

Given your problem, doing a simplification for a toy problem, in which you have only 2 values (called *y1* and *y2* here) and 2 costs (called *x1* and *x2* here), using max 2 values, one could formalize it in this way:

[image]

Where b1, b2, b3, b4 are the binary variables to set (0 or 1).

You can solve this problem (with *exact solution*) only by brute force. Using your real example, given all the useful combination with k repetition, with at least 1 value and max 4 values, you need to explore ([using number of combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)):

[image]

**714 solutions**. Which is feasible on a modern machine, and the *cheapest way* to solve your problem.

Alternatively one could use an *euristic algorithm* to get an *approximate solution*.

Comment: When he wrote *the cheapest method* he actually meant to minimize the output sum derived from his `cost` list, and not computionality cost.

Comment: @aryerez I think he meant the fastest method. Anyway, your method is the faster one